# Dash: Pie Chart not updating on call back

Tags: python, charts, callback, plotly-dash

I'm building a dashboard for our non-profit NGO and I've encountered a problem that is puzzling me:

**TL;DR Callback is working if I plot a bar or line chart. If I change it to a pie chart callback stops working**

I have a dynamic dataset ([sample here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vT5YoeIZZa2LSBrJQaMrTHhrWqg9cLeo-R9KEBo0InENacyJmqY54CqMH6pPDjpnLRq3yo29yR9qJXe/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true)) that updates every few minutes.

All runs without problems until I change the graph type to a pie chart.

I have set an interval

```
dcc.Interval(
           id='interval-component',
           interval=50*1000, # in milliseconds
           n_intervals=0
```

I then have a callback

```
@app.callback(
    Output('graph_actual', 'figure'),
    [Input('interval-component', "n_intervals")]
```

And then I get the latest information from the dataset and plot a new graph

```
url = "https://emergencias.pt/data"
    response  = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

    jsonResponse = json.loads(response.decode('utf-8'))

    df_new_actual = pd.json_normalize(jsonResponse['data'])

    df_new_actual['hour'] =pd.to_datetime(df_new_actual.hour)

    # sort values by date/time 

    df_new_actual.sort_values(by=['hour'])

    df_new_actual['total_meios'] = df_new_actual['man'] + df_new_actual['terrain']+df_new_actual['aerial']

    df_now_actual=df_new_actual.tail(10)

    print(df_now_actual)

    # Plot 
    fig_actual=px.bar(df_now_actual,x='hour',y='total_meios',color='naturezaName',
                #barmode='group', 
                template='plotly_white',
                color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.RdBu)
```

I have a gist with the [full code here](https://gist.github.com/JorgeMiguelGomes/f82ff5c99076f371a9599a88b7239a9a)

If I change px.bar to px.pie the callback stops working, for a reason I can't understand.
As you can see in the gist, I have first a pie chart and then a bar chart on the callback. This was on purpose so I could try and spot the problem.

TL;DR Callback is working if I plot a bar or line chart. If I change it to a pie chart callback stops working and doesn't update.

Any ideas of what's happening in here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike [bar](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/) or [line](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/) charts, [pie charts](https://plotly.com/python/pie-charts/) do not have `x` and `y` arguments, but rather `value` and `name`. If you have not adapted that, it is probably the reason its not working...

So have you tried something like this:

```
fig_actual=px.pie(df_now_actual,value='total_meios', name='hour',color='naturezaName',
                #barmode='group', 
                template='plotly_white',
                color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.RdBu)
```

Comment: Actually that was adapted properly.

Comment: can you create the pie plot outside of dash with the same data?

Comment: Yes, a static pie chart worked without problems. As I posted just now, I started from scratch and was able to make it work. It now updates without any problems. I have also added more elements to the dashboard and they are all in sync. In any case I do appreciate the time you took to try and help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So, after much tinkering I started from scratch (a clean setup) I was able to make it work. The working code [can be found here](https://gist.github.com/JorgeMiguelGomes/bf938308128afb1dd61bc4dfdd80f5fb), for future reference and in case anyone might run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem and was very baffled and frustrated. I just fixed it.

For me at least, the problem was that my callback had a code path that would go to the end and return a `None` for the figure *if nothing was selected in a dropdown*. This would happen when the page loaded, when most callbacks execute once initially. Apparently, this bad return value messed something up in the callback chain and *the callback never worked correctly after that initial bad return value*.

To fix this, at the top of my function I added something like this:

```py
    if selected_id is None:
        raise PreventUpdate
```

Which is [described in the docs](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks). Alternatively I could probably just make the callback function always return a valid graph. I am assuming that returning `None` to a figure in a callback is not supported and the result is [Nasal Demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and maybe the bar and line figures handle it better than a pie figure.